# Can an attacker predict value of $d$ if attacker already used $n$ for encryption?

Tags: encryption, rsa, cryptanalysis

In RSA we have value of n and e which is known to sender.
If the sender keep maintaining a database of possible n's he can easy calculate $\phi(n)$ because he already know $p$ and $q$ then. $d$ is $e^{-1} \mod \phi(n)$.

If we choose a large number which is product of two primes, can an attacker predict value of $d$?

Answer (score 1):

Technically you're right, if you get the two prime-factors of n (p and q), then you can calculate everything else pretty easily.

But that's the problem! There is no known way to calculate p and q efficiently, but it is also unproven, if there really isn't a suitable algorithm and RSA is purposefully implemented in that way.

This is actually one of the big unsolved questions in mathematics.

See:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization

Also your idea with storing a database of possible n's is infeasible, because this database would be unimaginably huge. You would have to store all possible calculations which would easily be greater than the number of atoms in the universe by far.

Comment: Neither Factoring nor the RSA Problem are known to be NP-Hard, therefore, finding a polynomial time algorithm to any of them has no impact on the P vs NP issue.

Comment: It's clearly of the class NP (second link) and _thought_ to be NP-complete, but as I said: unproven.

Comment: Even without storing, there's not enough energy in the universe to _compute_ all semiprimes, or the prime factors, for RSA sizes actually used.